# NeoVim won't show . files, like .gitignore or .prettierrc files

Tags: windows, powershell, vim, neovim

I recently started to use neovim in windows with windows-terminal, everything has been nice so far but I have a problem with the files or folders starting with '.', for whatever reason the NERDTree won't show me the '.' files, I don't really know if I'm missing a configuration or not. I've searched over google but cannot find anything. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NERDTree has a [NERDTreeShowHidden](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree/blob/b134f6518b902c7e0482ae770b804fd47c2d2426/doc/NERDTree.txt#L1044-L1053) option that tells vim whether to display hidden files. By default, this option is disabled, which means that started with `.` will be hidden. To change this behavior, you can add `let NERDTreeShowHidden=1` to your configuration file.

Comment: Thank you very much it was just what I needed!